# Apply the machine learning packages in R to a large data set

Tags: r, machine-learning, package, scalability, large-data

I have a data set that is about 1GB, which does not fit the memory (since when we apply LM in R, it also creates other variables that consume memory as well). I wonder if there is a way to still use those nice machine learning packages (e.g., glm, random forest, neural nets) in R to do the analysis in this situation? I appreciate any suggestion and reference.

Comment: check the "Large memory and out-of-memory data" section of the [HPC task view](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/HighPerformanceComputing.html)

Answer (score 3):

See the [high-performance task view on CRAN](https://cloud.r-project.org/web/views/HighPerformanceComputing.html), specifically the section on large memory and out-of-memory data.

Alternatively: you may have to pay money, but consider using [Microsoft R Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-r/). MRS, previously known as Revolution R Enterprise, is designed to break the memory barrier when it comes to working with large datasets. It's available for both Windows and Linux, and also allows in-database Analytics with SQL Server, Teradata, Hadoop (Cloudera, Hortonworks and HDInsight) and Spark.

Disclosure: I'm a Microsoft employee.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use Spark consider [sparklyr](http://spark.rstudio.com/) (free).

Comment: This would be a good comment to Hong's answer but itsn't really an answer by itself.

Comment: Answer was below. I've removed the "comment".